# What's the fastest way to concatenate all the values (each is a list) of a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

```py
LST = dict()
LST['A'] = [1,2,3]
LST['B'] = [4,5,6]
LST['C'] = [7,8,9]
...
LST['L'] = [0,5,8]
```

I have a dictionary of 12 key-list pairs.What's the fastest way to concatenate these 12 lists (all values of the dictionary) together? Basically, is there a one-liner to do the following?

```py
res = list()
for lst in LST.values():
    res.extend(lst)
```

Comment: Do you need any specific order in terms of keys? Else you may do this: `[n for l in LST.values() for n in l]`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Thank you! Order doesn't matter. But I'm trying very hard to understand your code lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this list comprehension:

```
res = [item for sublist in LST.values() for item in sublist ]
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
result = sum(LST.values(), [])
```

Or

```
result = [j for i in LST.values() for j in i]
```

Also:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(LST.values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, however one-liner to concatenate all values in lists in dict is:

```py
all_values = [l_elem for l in LST.values() for l_elem in l]
```